# Piece of code with constructor

Tags: solidity

Can you explain me what this piece of code does please?
i don't understand it at all.

```
 struct Candidate {
        uint id;
        string name;
        uint voteCount;
    }

mapping(uint => Candidate) public candidates;
uint public candidateCount;

constructor() public {
    addCandidate("candidate 1");
    addCandidate("candidate 2");
}

function addCandidate(string name) private {
    candidateCount += 1;
    candidates[candidateCount] = Candidate(candidateCount, name, 0);
}
```

Thank you very much

Take care

Answer (score 1):

The [`constructor`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.0/contracts.html#constructors) is a function that is called once, when you deploy a contract to the network. It cannot be called manually, after deployment. This code will run the `addCandidate` function twice on deployment, which adds new `Candidate`s to the `candidates` array (or mapping, it's not entirely clear from the snippet you posted).

`candidates[candidateCount] = ...`  basically assigns a value to the array, where the index is `candidateCount`. If the `candidateCount` is 0 by default, this will create a candidate for index 1 and 2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
"candidateCount" is a variable(I updated the code above).
So each time a candidate is entered in the fonction the variable "candidateCount" will be increased by 1?

Comment: Correct, `candidateCount += 1;` will increment it by one, every time the `addCandidate` function is called.